# How to update a FirefoxDriver (WebDriver) object when opening, and switching between tabs?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, tabs, selenium-firefoxdriver

Long time lurker; first time poster. I'm fairly new to the Selenium API and WebDriver, and I'm having a small problem.

In short, I am attempting to leverage the Firefox tab feature using Selenium's FirefoxDriver, but my driver instance object is not returning the correct URL using its getCurrentUrl() method when switching between tabs. Here is a brief example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
// display starting tab URL
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // expected output: google.com
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
// open new tab
if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")) {
    body.sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND + "t");
}
else {
    body.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
}
//navigate in new tab
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
// display new tab URL
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // expected output: yahoo.com
//navigate back to previous tab
body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
body.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +""+Keys.SHIFT +""+ Keys.TAB);
// display starting tab URL
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // expected output: google.com
driver.close();
```

However, on execution the output reads:

> google
>
> yahoo
>
> yahoo

My intuition suggests that the driver's frame/tab view is not being updated quickly enough, or at all, but I am not sure how to determine this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you really exploring the tab feature using Selenium or do you want some test case to succeed? Frankly, I never tried to use tabs with Selenium. But if you need some task getting done, I would suggest you to use windows instead of tabs. In that case WebDriver#switchTo() and WebDriver#getWindowHandle() should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm developing a FirefoxDriver sub-class that adds tabbing abilities in a way similar to how WebDriver handles window instances. Yes, I suppose I could simply use windows instead, but this is not the most ideal approach in my use-case.

Comment: ok, I've got no experience with tabs in Selenium. But if you think, it is a timing issue, try experimenting with `WebDriverWait` and/or `ExpectedConditions` to see, where it gets you. Good luck and I hope you (or someone else) will find a solution.

Comment: Thanks again. Turns out timing wasn't the primary issue, but thank you for the suggestion. Though after messing around with WebDriverWait for awhile, I gained some new ideas for other portions of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround to correct the driver's current view. After the driver switches to a different tab, a call to switchTo().defaultContent() must be made.

The working code is as follows:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
// display starting tab URL
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // expected output: google.com
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
// open new tab
if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")) {
    body.sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND + "t");
}
else {
    body.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
}
//navigate in new tab
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
// display new tab URL
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // expected output: yahoo.com
//navigate back to previous tab
body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
body.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +""+Keys.SHIFT +""+ Keys.TAB);
// refresh driver view
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
// display starting tab URL
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // expected output: google.com
driver.close();
```

The new resulting output now matches what is expected:

> google
>
> yahoo
>
> google